# Amazon SES error: The From ARN is not a valid SES identity

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ses

I am new to amazone SES and trying to set up my .net core API to send emails using SES. Here is code I`m using to send emails:

```
SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest();
        request.FromEmailAddress = "email@outlook.com";//verified
        //request.
        Destination destination= new Destination();
        destination.ToAddresses = new List<string> {"some verified email"};
        request.Destination = destination;
        EmailContent content = new EmailContent();
        
        content.Simple = new Message
        {
            Body = new Body
            {
                Html = new Content
                {
                    Data = $@"<html>
                    //here is some code
                    </html>"
                }
            },
            Subject = new  Content{
                Data = "some subject"
            }
        };
        request.Content = content;
        request.FromEmailAddressIdentityArn = senderArn;
        var status = await _sesClient.SendEmailAsync(request);
```

This code gives me such error: `The From ARN <arn:aws:ses:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx> is not a valid SES identity`.
On AWS console emails are verified: [image: screenshot from console]

Any ideas what I`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is .NET Code that does work. The sender has to be verified in SES. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/creating-identities.html.

```
public async void SendMessage(string text, string toAddress)
{
       var sesClient = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
       var sender = "scmacdon@amazon.com";
       var emailList = new List<string>();
       emailList.Add(toAddress);

       var destination = new Destination
            {
                ToAddresses = emailList
            };

            var content = new Content
            {
                Data = text
            };

            var sub = new Content
            {
                Data = "Amazon Rekognition Report"
            };

            var body = new Body
            {
                Text = content
            };

            var message = new Message
            {
                Subject = sub,
                Body = body
            };

            var request = new SendEmailRequest
            {
                Message = message,
                Destination = destination,
                Source = sender
            };

            try
            {
                await sesClient.SendEmailAsync(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Update
Make sure you are using this version.

[image]

Comment: `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient` is not applicable in SES API v2. It uses `IAmazonSimpleEmailServiceV2`. Other things are made as described in docs (email is verified, all required SendEmailRequest fields provided). So your answer is not working in my environment(

Comment: Best practice is to use the V3 version of the SES .NET SDK. I would use NuGET and get latest .NET packages.

Comment: This package version is the latest one. It is named V2 (even if SDK version is V3). I don`t know why, but this does not have any changes for me.

Comment: See the new screen shot

Comment: I moved back to the older package (which is used by you), and now everything is working. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you got it working